# Ввод из консоли

Tags: java, вывод, ввод

Всем Привет. Возникла необходимость считывать пользовательский ввод до тех пор пока не встретим три знака равно. Но код именно выполняется при условии что мы ввели три знака равно. Как реализовать так, что бы после ввода "===" ввод заканчивался.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = "";
        while ("===" != in.nextLine()) {
            input = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println(input);
        }

        System.out.println(input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для сравнения строк используйте метод `equals()`:

```
while (!"===".equals(in.nextLine())) {
```

В вашем случае сравниваются ссылки на объекты.

Также вы два раза считываете с консоли: в условии цикла while и в теле цикла. Достаточно одного раза.

Comment: Все равно программа работает некорректно.

Comment: @РоманКавыршин дополнил ответ. Достаточно в условии цикла считывать данные из консоли и делать проверку, либо наоборот в теле цикла делать проверку и при необходимости выходить из него, используя break.

Comment: Теперь работает. Спасибо! =)

Answer (score 0):

Если не нужно сохранять символы, то можно так:
Вводим счетчик подряд идущих знаков равенств, как только он достигает трех - выходим.
Собственно, если нужно сохранять считанное, то не проблема добавить какой-нибудь StringBuilder.

```
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int eqCount = 0;
        while(true){
            int c = br.read();
            if(c == '='){
                eqCount++;
            } else {
                eqCount = 0;
            }
            if(eqCount >= 3 || c == -1){
                break;
            }
        }
```